# Postgresql 9.1: ERROR: type "citext" does not exist

Tags: postgresql-9.1

I am trying to execute following query through PgAdmin utility.

```
CREATE TABLE svcr."EventLogs" ("eventId" BIGINT NOT NULL, 
"eventTime" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, "userid" CITEXT, 
"realmid" CITEXT NOT NULL, "onUserid" CITEXT, "description" TEXT, 
CONSTRAINT eventlogs_pkey PRIMARY KEY ("eventId"));
```

And I get following error -

```
ERROR: type "citext" does not exist
SQL state: 42704
Character: 120
```

However, following query runs fine -

```
CREATE TABLE svcr."CategoryMap" ("category" INT NOT NULL, 
"userData" INT NOT NULL);
```

What is wrong with the first query?

Comment: It's using a column type that doesn't exist in postgesql, just like the message says v

Answer (score 12, accepted):

what version of pg are you using? in < 8.4, citext can be installed as an add-on:

http://pgxn.org/dist/citext/

in >= 8.4 it should be available in core.

there are also some upgrade notes for 9.1.2 here:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/release-9-1-2.html

you may need to load the citext extension:

CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS citext WITH SCHEMA ext;

Comment: Yes, I had install the extension. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

pgadmin -> [your database] -> extensions -> create extension -> pick a **citext** from dropdown and save